# PHP page in the wwwroot folder

Tags: php, apache, upload, ftp

I am trying to upload my localhost site that I am making to the live server. Before I did that I made a test with a "hello world" index.php

When I place my index.php on the following path the page is working:

**but** that is not in the wwwroot.

When I place the index.php in the wwwroot folder I do not get to the hello world page. I just get the domain page.

How can this be? I also noticed that my page should be dangerous in the URL bar. It is just a portfolio, there is nothing dangerous on that site.

Comment: Can you post DOCUMENT_ROOT value in phpinfo output for this server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I do that :-/

Comment: make a file `test.php` on server with following content: `<?php  phpinfo();` , in browser open url of file and check. add it outside of wwwroot.

Comment: you need to set your DOCUMENT_ROOT from `/customers/0/f/c/vouzalis.com/httpd.www` to `/customers/0/f/c/vouzalis.com/httpd.www/wwwroot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to discussion in comment,
You need to set/change your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directive as below

`DOCUMENT_ROOT /customers/0/f/c/vouzalis.com/httpd.www`

to

`DOCUMENT_ROOT /customers/0/f/c/vouzalis.com/httpd.www/wwwroot`

If you are not managing your server, you can ask hosting for setup.

Comment: THanks Ravi. Which file I have to do that? is it in a config file?

Comment: On your server, there may be file at following path `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` .

Comment: If you are not managing your server, don't edit files. but take help of server administrators.

Comment: Is that in the local Apache server or live server. I was just chatting with one.com, and they said they could not help me. I am admin of the page, but it is just the first time I lay a page online. I thought it was easy to do.

Comment: No you need to do it in live server (vouzalis.com). If it is a shared hosting they may not allow to change document root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122483/discussion-between-ravi-and-mcduck4).

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify your Apache VirtualHost configuration. You need something like:

```
DocumentRoot /wwwroot/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that in a file in apache server I have to that?